# How to convert time() to the format of 09/02/2010 in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, formatting

```
$ts = time();
```

How to convert `$ts` to the format `09/02/2010` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the date() function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php. You'd want either:

```
date('d/m/Y', $ts)
```

or:

```
date('m/d/Y', $ts)
```

Depending on the format you need ("09/02/2010" is ambiguous, it could be either).

Comment: Seems seconds is lot easier to deal with in PHP than unix timestamps,right?

Comment: @wamp What do you mean by that? Unix timestamps are the number of seconds since the Unix epoch (1st January 1970). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time for more information on that.

Comment: It depends on what you're doing with your timestamp. As a rule, you *absolutely should not* be doing arithmetic on a seconds-based timestamp because you will come a cropper eventually with things like daylight-saving. Use the inbuilt date manipulation functions instead.

Comment: @wamp Unix timestamps are what time() returns, there is no difference :)